# How to generate random position on a grid?

Tags: javascript, math, grid

I have a 9600x9600 map full of 48x48 tiles and I'm trying to place 96x96 objects to  random points, I can get a random point and place the object there but i couldn't figure out how to place them correctly near the edges.

[It looks like this when placed near the edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YizTs.png) (Red box is where it's placed)

I want them to be placed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXFHH.png) instead so it's in the center of a 48x48x48 area

I get random positions using this function:

```
  this.playArea = [9600, 9600]
  getRandomPosition(size) {
    const x = getRandomInt(0, this.playArea[0] / size);
    const y = getRandomInt(0, this.playArea[1] / size);
    return { x: x * size, y: y * size };
  }
  position = getRandomPosition(48)
```

I probably just need to add a simple math to the function but i don't know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Constrain your random number generator to a smaller size

The issue you're running into is caused by allowing a value that is too close to the edge. To remedy that you need to pass `widthOfGrid - widthOfBox` and `heightOfGrid - heightOfBox` like so:

```js
  this.playArea = [9600, 9600]
  getRandomPosition(size) {
    const x = getRandomInt(1, (this.playArea[0] - size) / size);
    const y = getRandomInt(1, (this.playArea[1] - size) / size);
    return { x: x * size, y: y * size };
  };
```

That should produce only numbers up to the edge minus one of `size`.

Comment: Thanks, addıng `-size` and making minimum number `1` did the trick.